# The type or namespace name 'GameManager' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I've been trying for some days to write some code for my first game such that if the user doesn't watch the full rewarded video ad (from admob) and he closes it earlier, he doesn't claim the actual reward that is an extra life.
The first thing I tried to do was to move the GameObject (with the "ads script" associated) from the Menu Scene to the Game Scene, because it was easier to have access to functions from game scene, I guess..
After watching some tutorials, here are is the code for the Rewarded Video Ad:

```
public class ads : MonoBehaviour
{
private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
private void RequestReward()
    {
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
        this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adUnitId);

        this.rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
        this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += this.HandleOnRewarded;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);
    }
public void ShowRewardVideo()
    {
        if (this.rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.rewardedAd.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Reward video is not ready yet");
        }
    }
public void HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ShowRewardVideo();
    }
public void HandleOnRewarded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      // SO, If I understand properly, if I want players not to receive the extra life<br>
      before the reward video is finished, I have to write here the code for receiving the extra life 
      instead of writing it in the GameManager script. (script that is down below)

    }
public void HandleOnRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
        this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward -= this.HandleOnRewarded;
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
    }
```

Here I have the 2 functions from GameScript that allow me show the ad:
the first one, that is called when pressing the in-game button "Watch for extra life"

```
public void ShowReward()
{
        birdParent.SetActive(false);
        ads.instance.ShowRewardVideo();
        gameOverCanvas.SetActive(false);
        score.SetActive(false);
      ->rewardPanel.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
}
```

After clicking that button and the video starts playing, as you can see in the function, the panel with the reward is activated (no matter you watched the full video or closed it). And then, after finishing the video, you get back to the game where you have a panel that says something like "Thank you for watching the video, here is your extra life. Press OK". And when button OK is pressed, this function is called

```
public void ContinueAfterReward()
{
    score.SetActive(true);
    rewardPanel.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    Start();
    GameHasStarted();
    bird.Start();
    bird.Update();
    score.SetActive(true);
}
```

The problem is that these 2 functions are in the 'GameManager' script (which is in the GameManager object) but I want them to integrate somehow in that script that is in 'ads' script (which is in the standard GameObject object), so I can insert or call the functions inside that handle tool, in order to prevent the user to skip the video if he wants to earn the reward. I tried to declare a 'public GameManager gameManager' inside ads script (so after that I should be able to call the functions inside ads script) but it simply doesn't work, I get the error from the title.
I don't know if you've understood what I want to do but please if you have any idea write a reply because I'm struggling with this thing for some hours and just can't figure out.. or if you know any other way to do this.. :)

EDIT:
[image]

So, basically, here in GameObject I have the script 'ads' and inside it I would want to call some functions from the 'GameManager' script from the GameManager object. And even if I declared public static GameManager instance in the GM script, I am not able to call either GameManager.instance.ShowReward() or public GameManager GameManager inside ads script. How should do I do that?

[image]

[image]

the interesting thing is, as you can see in the last photo, i have a bird game object with a bird script associated, and inside it i can call the gamemanager script.. and it's not because of the capital leter, i tried both gameManager and GameManager

[image]

Comment: Cant reproduce the error from the included code. Please include a [mre] in the question.

Comment: Is it clearer now, @Ruzihm?

Comment: sounds like you don't have a script called `GameManager`

Comment: I've edited the post again and you can see I have one :(, @Ruzihm

Comment: It says there's a compile error in `GameManager`. please include the compile error in  `GameManager`

Comment: The error comes actually from the ads script, because I wrote "GameManager.instance.ShowReward()", if I comment that line I get no errors inside GameManager.. so the error is not from the GM script, but from the ads

Comment: One last good faith guess until a [mre] is included in the question. You might have `GameManager` in a namespace that `ads` isn't in, so you'll need to either use `NameSpaceName.GameManager.instance...` or include `using NameSpaceName;` at the top of `ads.cs`. Hope that helps and good luck.

Comment: Actually one more. You should consider having `GameManager` extend `MonoBehaviour`, if it isn't already. (sorry if this is something obvious but without a [mre] I can't know if you've already done this or not)

Comment: It is monobehaviour. I've read the topic with the minimal reproducible example but i think here i've already provided all the code that is necessary, from both scripts :(. The problem is the ads script doesn't recognize that I have another script, gamemanager.. i've edited the post with those scripts

Comment: But thank you a lot for trying to help and wasting your time with me, I will still try to search which could be the problem..

Comment: That's a lot more helpful thank you. Looks like the error says line 75, but `GameManager.instance.ShowReward()`, is on line 79, so that does not seem to be the cause, but then I notice that the script isn't saved (has a `*` after `GameManager.cs`), so the line number in the error is not helpful... Can you save all of the files and then show the error with line number?

Comment: Done, both scripts are saved

Comment: the interesting thing is, as you can see in the last photo, i have a bird game object with a bird script associated, and inside it i can call the gamemanager script :)))).. and it's not because of the capital leter, i tried both gameManager and GameManager

Comment: Yeah, that is interesting. It sounds like Unity is trying to force `ads` to compile before `GameManager`. Can you show the solution explorer? I wonder if they are in different assemblies. I would try going into the unity editor and moving `ads` out of the `GoogleMobileAds` directory and into a different `Assets` directory, as it's possible that `GoogleMobileAds` is configured to compile first.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS. I couldn't imagine something like this could happen in unity :))))) thanks a lot for all your help, it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, all signs point to Unity trying to force `ads` to compile before `GameManager`.

Go into the Unity editor and move `ads` out of the `GoogleMobileAds` directory and into a different `Assets` directory, as it's possible that `GoogleMobileAds` is specifically configured to compile first/early.

In the unlikely event that doesn't work, put `ads` in the same directory as `GameManager`.